# How to create lookalike audience by choosing PIXEL_ID as a source (just like in UI Interface) using Facebook Marketing API

Tags: api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I can create lookalike audience in Audience manager (GUI interface) but I can't find it in facebook marketing api  documentation.

As this mentions [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/lookalike-audiences) only three ways to create lookalike audience, but I can't find any thing related as a solution to my problem.

- Existing Custom Audiences
- Campaign or Ad Set conversions
- Page fans

Thanks.